# Cut Special String - VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

my Question is how to check if a string have a  "text" &  "_" at beginning.

For Example:

```
If sText = test.docx Then Function = False
 ElseIF sText = Test_test.docx Then Function = True
End If
```

how i cut this string correctly, also when the text before the _ is not test and if there are several _ in the string it also works

Comment: You might like to look at Split

Comment: you can use `Instr`. Try this example: If InStr(1, "Test_abcde", "test" & "_", vbTextCompare) = 1 then`

Comment: You can also use the `Like` operator: `If sText Like "Test_*" Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Instr() as shown here:

```
foo="test"&"_"
bar="test_test.docx"
if Instr(bar, foo)>0 then function = true
else function = false
end if
```

Instr(bar,foo) shows position of substring foo in string bar.
If there s no such substring, then it returns zero
If you need to check any text, that is not a problem, use this condition:

```
foo="_"
n=4
bar"test_textt.docx"
m=Instr(bar,foo)
if (m>n)and(len(bar)>m) then function=true
else function=false
end if
```

here n - number of characters, that would be before "*"
If you dont know how many characters there may be, just set n to 0 or 1
if "*" migth be last character, then delete condition `(len(bar)>m)`

Comment: hello mister, thanks for your answer, but this should be possible with any text

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works fine!

Answer (score -1):

You can simply check if the string begin with test_

```
dim res as boolean, filename as string
res = false
filename = ""
' if the len is not Superior to 5 (len of test_), don't check
if len(sText) > 5 then
  ' if the left part begin with test_ 
  if left(lcase(sText), 5) = "test_" then
    res = true
    ' if you want to retrieve the filename without test
    filename = mid(sText, 6) 
  end if
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but the beginning could also be ABC_ or AD_, so the solution must be a other

Comment: Sorry, I misread, I thought you wanted to check "Test_" instead of "any Text". Do you want to check for any text? or possible text are preset?

Comment: is the text can be numbers ? like 123_ or A23_